# mongoose one to many ref is returning stale data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

When updating a product in mongoose, and  a user (that created it) has a ref to that product. the product gets updated. However when populating the users-product (by calling user.products) it doesn't spit out the updated version of the product. just the stale previous one. Can someone help

this is the code for when the product is listed and it gets pushed to the users many products

```
   module.exports.listProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.user.email });
    imageUploads(req, res, async (err) => {
      if (err) return res.json({ err });
      const product = req.body;
      const newListedProd = new Product({
        mainImageUrl: req.files[0].location,
        title: product.title,
        location: product.location,
        price: product.price,
        description: product.description,
        category: product.category,
        canDeliver: product.canDeliver || false,
        galleryImages: req.files.map((f) => ({
          imageUrl: f.location,
          imageKey: f.key,
          size: f.size,
        })),
        user,
      });
      const productFromDb = await newListedProd.save();
      user.productsListed.push(productFromDb.toObject());
      let savedUser = await user.save();
      return res.json({ prod: productFromDb, user: savedUser }); //sends back data
    });
  } catch (er) {
    return res.json({ er });
  }
};
```

This is the code when updating a product

```
module.exports.updateListedProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    // will need to be based on user...
    const newListedItem = await Product.findById(req.params.id);
newListedItem.title = req.body.title;
 const updatedProduct = await updateListedProd.save();
    return res.json(updatedProduct);
}
```

the product is updated.

But when I call

```
userFromDb = await User.findOne({ email: user.email }).populate('productsListed.product')
```

the products that come from user.products don't have the new changes

Comment: Please note that you should post your code if you would like assistance.

Comment: Added code snippets

Comment: and the schema? `user.productsListed.push(productFromDb.toObject())` looks wrong and `.populate('productsListed.product')` too.

Comment: btw, I think your variable naming convention could use some work as well. The variables should be descriptive. Example: "createdProduct", "updatedProduct". Makes it easier on you later as well.

Comment: Another thing is I highly recommend Postman and Robo 3T. Robo 3T is a desktop app that'll enable you to connect to your Mongo database.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're pushing the created product into the User model is the reason why you're not seeing the updated product information.

Instead, the "products" property in the model should be an array with references to the product ID's.

**Example User schema**

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    products: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Product"
    }]
});
```

Now, if you want to add ID's of products to this in your code you can simply find the user, then do something like the below. The **products** coming from the post request (body) will be an array of product ID's. Populate will be used to pull the information for the product.

```
const {products} = req.body; //array of products from body
const foundUser = await User.findOne({email: req.params.email});
if(foundUser){
    foundUser.products.push(...products);
    const updatedUser = await foundUser.save();
    res.json(updatedUser);
} else {
    // handle 404 user not found
}
```

Getting the user with product information...

```
const userWithProducts = await User.find({email: req.params.email}).populate("product", "id name price");
```

Comment: Thanks Tony. Yea it was how those issues.  Fixed now!

Comment: Awesome! New to the back end stuff myself as well. Can be quite tricky at times :)